# Variable out of bounds

Tags: c#, variables

I'm just learning about C# and i created a simple program to get a persons BMI but the issue that I'm having is that while my program can get the rest of my variables it can't get one. What happens when I run it is that it says that it can't get the weightclass variable due to it being out of bounds whereas if i remove the weightclass from the console.writeline part of the code then the program will run without issues.

```
Console.WriteLine("what's your weight in pounds");
    string weight = Console.ReadLine();
    float weighnum = Single.Parse(weight);
    weight = weighnum.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("what's your height in inches");
    string height = Console.ReadLine();
    float heightnum = Single.Parse(weight);
    height = heightnum.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("what's your gender");
    string gender = Console.ReadLine();



    float bmi = ((weighnum) / ((heightnum) * (heightnum)) * 703);
    if (bmi < 17.5 & gender == "f")
    { string weightclass = "anorexic"; }
    else if (bmi > 17.5 & bmi < 19.1 & gender == "f")
    { string weightclass = "underweight"; }
    else if (bmi > 19.1 & bmi <25.8 & gender == "f")
    { string weightclass = "normal range"; }
    else if (bmi > 25.8 & bmi < 27.3 & gender == "f")
    { string weightclass = "marginally overweight"; }
    else if (bmi > 27.3 & bmi < 32.3 & gender == "f")
    { string weightclass = "overweight"; }
    else if (bmi > 32.3 & bmi < 35 & gender == "f")
    { string weightclass = "obese"; }
    else if (bmi > 35 & bmi < 40 & gender == "f")
    { string weightclass = "severely obese"; }
    else if (bmi > 40 & bmi < 50 & gender == "f")
    { string weightclass = "morbidly obese"; }
    else if (bmi > 50  & gender == "f")
    { string weightclass = "super obese"; }
    else if (bmi < 20 & gender == "m")
    { string weightclass = "underweight"; }
    else if (bmi >= 20 & bmi <= 25 & gender == "m")
    { string weightclass = "normal range"; }
    else if (bmi > 25 & gender == "m")
    { string weightclass = "marginally overweight"; }
    else if (bmi < 20 & gender == "m")
    { string weightclass = "overweight"; }
    else if (bmi >= 20 & bmi <= 25 & gender == "m")
    { string weightclass = "obese"; }
    else if (bmi > 25 & gender == "m")
    { string weightclass = "severely obese"; }
    else if (bmi < 20 & gender == "m")
    { string weightclass = "morbidly obese"; }
    else if (bmi >= 20 & bmi <= 25 & gender == "m")
    { string weightclass = "super obese"; }

    Console.WriteLine("your bmi is " + bmi + " this means that you are " + weightclass);




    }
}
}
```

Comment: When you ask these questions, try to be as specific with the error text as you can. You should be getting something more like "The name "variablename" does not exist in the current context", out of bounds means you've done something wrong while indexing an array.

Comment: You need to find a way to better organize your code, because it is unclear know if all input combinations are handled by the if statements. It looks like they are not: no combination of the if statements triggers, so *weightclass* does not get assigned. One way to at least prevent that is to create *weightclass* and assign it a value at the top of your code, like *"unknown"*. That way you would immediately see that the entered combination of values slips through the cracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the declaration of your `weightclass`-variablke outside any `else`-block:

```
float bmi = ((weighnum) / ((heightnum) * (heightnum)) * 703);
string weightclass = null;

if (bmi < 17.5 & gender == "f")
{ weightclass = "anorexic"; }
else if (bmi > 17.5 & bmi < 19.1 & gender == "f")
...
```

The problem occurs because every variable is bound to its scope where it is declared. This when you declare one within a `else`-block you cannot access it otside that specific scope. [Further information on scopes can be found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Ah, thanks I tried moving it outside but I must have moved it too far out of it.